# Repeat Pandas data frame based on a value and add the counter back to the data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

let's say you have the following data frame:

```
item_a item_b
1       123
7       32   
4       18
```

and then you have a constant `PERIODS = 3', how do I repeat the above data frame by 3 times while adding each repetition as a counter.

**The desired outcome is:**

```
counter item_a item_b
1       1       123
1       7       32   
1       4       18
2       1       123
2       7       32   
2       4       18
3       1       123
3       7       32   
3       4       18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, which simply concatenates your df however many times you want, setting the index as a progressively increasing constant with each concatenation:

```
import numpy as np

period=3

new_df = pd.concat([df.set_index(np.repeat(i, len(df))) for i in range(1,period+1)])

>>> new_df
   item_a  item_b
1       1     123
1       7      32
1       4      18
2       1     123
2       7      32
2       4      18
3       1     123
3       7      32
3       4      18

# Or, to have counter as a separate column rather than the index:
new_df = pd.concat([df.assign(counter=np.repeat(i, len(df))) 
                    for i in range(1,period+1)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Solution 2**

Seeing as, from your comment, you are looking for speedy code execution, this method is faster:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat([df.values],period, axis=0).reshape(-1,df.shape[1]), 
             index=np.repeat(range(1,period+1), len(df)), columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Which method would be faster in let's say an 80,000 row pandas file?

Comment: I just timed the two, and the concat method was a lot faster than the groupby method for an 80000 row df (0.67 seconds for 100 iterations vs. 5.9 seconds for 100 iterations)

Comment: @sacul if speed is the key please mention it in the op.thanks

Comment: @Wen, I agree, though I didn't know speed was the key, I just timed it at the request of the OP...

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `reindex`, then we recreate the index by using `groupby` `cumcount`

```
s=df.reindex(df.index.tolist()*3)
s.index=s.groupby(s.index).cumcount()+1
s
Out[1349]: 
   item_a  item_b
1       1     123
1       7      32
1       4      18
2       1     123
2       7      32
2       4      18
3       1     123
3       7      32
3       4      18
```